# Display Video Frame of WebCam in C# Window Form

Tags: c#

I am currently using my Webcam to display video frame by creating another window. However, I had reserved a box for video displaying in my window form application and try not to create another window for video frame. How could i do it?

Attach my code for creating new video:

```
 VideoCapture capture;
        Mat frame;

        capture = new VideoCapture();
        frame = new Mat();
        capture.Open(0);
        string imageFilePath = "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\source\\repos\\FaceDetection\\FaceDetection\\test1.jpg";
        //// Read the video stream

        Cv2.NamedWindow("Video", WindowMode.AutoSize);
        while (true)
        {
            if (capture.Read(frame))
            {
                Cv2.ImShow("Video", frame);
             }
         }
```

My window form application:

```
private void EmoStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        VideoCapture capture;
        Mat frame;
        string imageFilePath = "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\source\\repos\\FaceDetection\\FaceDetection\\test1.jpg";
        capture = new VideoCapture();
        frame = new Mat();
        capture.Open(0);
        while (true)
        {
            if (capture.Read(frame))
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = capture.Read(frame);
            }
        }
    }
```

Could the picture box read the captured frame?
When i try to open up another windows, both of them are freezed.
How could i attach the Webcam frame to my application form?
Thank you!